# insert data array from dynamic form to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i have a dynamic form. in form i can add multiple field as much as I want. but I am confused how to save it into the database.

this my form code, just like this but little diferent https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q8zj00s0/1/

```
   <form id="tambahepisode" method="post" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></form>
<form>
  <ul id="fieldList">
    <li>
      <input name="name[]" type="text" placeholder="Name" form="tambahepisode"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input name="phone[]" type="text" placeholder="Phone" form="tambahepisode"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input name="email[]" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" form="tambahepisode"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="addMore">Add more fields</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Publikasi" form="tambahepisode" style="width: 100%;" />
</form>
```

and here my jquery to create dynamic form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
  $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fieldList").append("<li>&nbsp;</li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Name' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='phone[]' placeholder='Phone' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='email[]' placeholder='E-Mail' /></li>");
  });
});

</script>
```

my basic insert to database

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name= htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        $phone= htmlentities($_POST['phone']);
        $email= htmlentities($_POST['email']);
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `data`(`name`,`phone`,`email`)
        VALUES (:name,:phone,:email)");
        $query->bindParam(":name", $name);
        $query->bindParam(":phone", $phone);
        $query->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $query->execute();
        header("location: index.php");
    }
```

Comment: Your $name is an array. Check it and Lemme  know.

Comment: Not just the $name, even $phone and $email is an array... You have to loop over the $_POST[...] arrays to transform them. `array_map` should help you. For insert into the database, do a for-loop.

Comment: ya, that basic code to insert to databse. i dont know how to create insert to database based my form code.

Comment: Then just iterate the those value, added into query and submit.
Or you can create your custom sql query like Values(`v1`,'v2', 'v3'), ('v4', 'v5', 'v6');

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to count how much no of record you want to save, as you want save array by add more button.

For example count name or any other field.

```
$count = count($_POST['name']);
```

Then use foreach or for loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $name= htmlentities($_POST['name'][$i]);
    $phone= htmlentities($_POST['phone'][$i]);
    $email= htmlentities($_POST['email'][$i]);
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `data`(`name`,`phone`,`email`)
        VALUES (:name,:phone,:email)");
    $query->execute();        
}
header("location: index.php");
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `foreach` instead. It is much faster than `for`: http://www.phpbench.com/